# How to add/remove item on the basis of checkbox checked or unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have written below lines of code

```js
var selectedFinal = [];
//On click check all records
$(document).on("click", "#completebatch,.commoncheckbox", function() {

  var checkBoxCount = 0;
  var selected = [];

  $("#selected_students").empty();

  $('#studentListBody input:checked').not(".disabled-check").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    if ($("#" + id).is(":checked")) {
      checkBoxCount++;
      selected.push(id);
    } else {
      checkBoxCount--;
      selected.pop(id);
    }
  });

  $("#allStudentIds").val($.unique(selected));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><input onclick="checkenabledisable()" id="completebatch" type="checkbox"></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox disabled-check" value="578" type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="357" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="123" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have created html table with checkboxes, where user can uncheck or check the checkboxes. Based on checked or unchecked checkboxes  I am trying to push the id's (value) of the checked checkboxes in the "selected" array. The above code is not adding the value of that checkbox. Also When I try to uncheck the checkbox that id is not removed from the "selected" array. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't simply use `map()` and `get()` on the `checked` check boxes:

```js
var selectedFinal = [];
//On click check all records
$(document).on("click", "#completebatch,.commoncheckbox", function () { 
    selectedFinal = $('.commoncheckbox:checked').map((i,el) =>{
    return $(el).attr('value')
  }).get();
  console.log(selectedFinal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><input onclick="checkenabledisable()" id="completebatch" type="checkbox"></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox disabled-check"  value="578" type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="357" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="123" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try executing the following script:

```
 <tbody>
<tr>
  <td><input class="commoncheckbox disabled-check"  id = "checkbox1" value="578" type="checkbox" onclick="check(this.id);" disabled=""></td>
 <td>abc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="357"  id = "checkbox2" onclick="check(this.id);" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>abc</td>
</tr>
<tr>

  <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="123" id = "checkbox3"  onclick="check(this.id);" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>abc</td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>



<script>
selected = [];
function check(a){
    if(document.getElementById(a).checked = true){
        selected.push(document.getElementById(a).value); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix as well your code on this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/792746/

```
// find elements
var selectedFinal = [];
$( document ).ready(function() {
             //On click check all records

                var checkBoxCount = 0;
                var selected = [];


                $('input:checkbox.commoncheckbox').not(".disabled-check").change(function (event) {

                    var target = event.target;
                    if ($(target).is(":checked"))
                    {
                        checkBoxCount++;
                        selected.push(target.value);
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        checkBoxCount--;
                        selected.pop(target.value);
                    }
                    console.log('selected', selected)
                });

                $("#allStudentIds").val($.unique(selected));

           });
```